# Powershell Regex to Extract Specific Patterns from Input Strings

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to extract certain patterns from input strings using PowerShell regex. The input strings follow a specific format with tags and attributes. Here are the two examples:

##### Example 1:

```
<S> A[a/DT,B-NP-singular] Whole[whole/JJ,whole/NN,whole/RP,I-NP-singular] New[New/JJ,New/NNP,new/JJ,I-NP-singular] Mind[mind/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] Why[why/CC,why/NN,why/UH,why/WRB,B-ADVP] Right-Brainers[Right-Brainers/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] Will[will/MD,B-VP] Rule[rule/VB,I-VP] the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] Future[future/JJ,future/NN:UN,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>
```

##### Example 2:

```
<S> Bit[bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] By[by/IN,by/JJ,by/NN,by/RP,B-PP] Bit[bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] How[how/WRB,B-ADVP] P2P[P2P/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] Is[Is/NNP,be/VBZ,B-VP] Changing[change/VBG,I-VP] the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] World[world/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] by[by/IN,B-PP] John[John/NNP,B-NP-singular] Smith[Smith/NNP,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>
```

I want to extract the following patterns:

**(1) B-NP-Singular and E-NP-Singular pairs**

**(2) B-NP-Singular E-NP-Singular B-PP B-NP-Singular E-NP-Singular pairs**

In the provided examples, the expected extractions are as follows:

**For Example 1:**

1. Whole New Mind
2. Right-Brainers
3. the Future

**For Example 2:**

1. Bit By Bit
2. P2P
3. the World
4. John Smith

- 

In my example code I used the regex below it somehow works (not fully captures) with the online regex tester (https://www.regextester.com/) but running the Pester test script it's always $null:

```
Describe "Noun Phrase Extraction" {
    $text = @"
<S> Bit[bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] By[by/IN,by/JJ,by/NN,by/RP,B-PP] Bit[bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] How[how/WRB,B-ADVP] P2P[P2P/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] Is[Is/NNP,be/VBZ,B-VP] Changing[change/VBG,I-VP] the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] World[world/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] by[by/IN,B-PP] John[John/NNP,B-NP-singular] Smith[Smith/NNP,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>
Disambiguator log:

STEP_BY_STEP[1]: Bit[bit/NN*,bite/VBD*,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] -> Bit[bit/NN*,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular]

STEP_BY_STEP[1]: By[by/IN,by/JJ,by/NN,by/RP,B-PP] -> By[by/IN,by/JJ,by/NN,by/RP,B-PP]

STEP_BY_STEP[1]: Bit[bit/NN,bite/VBD,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] -> Bit[bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular]

HOW_WRB[1]: How[How/NNP,how/NN,how/WRB,B-ADVP] -> How[how/WRB,B-ADVP]

DT_JJNN_IN_NN[1]: World[world/JJ,world/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] -> World[world/NN:UN,E-NP-singular]

IN_NN_PRP[1]: by[by/IN,by/JJ,by/NN,by/RP,B-PP] -> by[by/IN,B-PP]

UPPER_NNP[1]: John[John/NNP,john/NN,B-NP-singular] -> John[John/NNP,B-NP-singular]

UPPER_NNP[1]: Smith[Smith/NNP,smith/NN,Smith/SENT_END,E-NP-singular] -> Smith[Smith/NNP,Smith/SENT_END,E-NP-singular]

5602 rules activated for language English (US)
"@

    It "should capture Noun Phrases using Regex" {
        $regexPattern = '(?<=\B)[A-Za-z]+(?=\[.*?B-NP-singular.*?\])(?:.*?)([A-Za-z]+)(?=\[.*?E-NP-singular.*?\])'

        $regexOptions = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase
        $regex = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex $regexPattern, $regexOptions
 
        $nounPhrases = $regex.Matches($text)

        Write-Host "Matches: $($nounPhrases | Out-String)"

        foreach ($match in $nounPhrases) {
          $phrase = $match.Groups[1].Value
          Write-Host "Found phrase: $phrase" 
        }

        $capturedPhrases = @()

        foreach ($phrase in $nounPhrases) {
            $capturedPhrases += $phrase.Groups[1].Value
        }

        $capturedPhrases | Should -not -BeNullOrEmpty
    }
}
```

What could be wrong with the regex?

Comment: Are you looking for help with regex or with understanding why the Pester test fails? If for the Pester test, it's just that `$text` should be defined in the `BeforeAll` block.

Comment: What are pairs in your requirements? And why is `Whole New Mind` an expected result when `I-NP-singular` is not listed in your extraction definitions?

Comment: Do you need to capture [like this](https://regex101.com/r/Z0ADA0/2)? Approx. `\b([A-Za-z]+)\[([^][]*(?:[BE]-NP-singular|B-PP)[^][]*)]`?

Comment: To save anyone else looking it up, the OPs strings look like they were generated by "LanguageTool" - if you paste "A Whole New Mind Why Right-Brainers Will Rule the Future" into the online text analyser at https://community.languagetool.org/analysis/analyzeText you'll get results that look like a tabular version of the sample string...

Comment: @mclayton right, it is generated the LanguageTool v6.3, which the command line is fed with the audiobook titles from a vast index of unorganized titles which we need to get the Noun Phrases to be able to match the unorganized titles efficiently with the indexed titles, the unorganized or raw and long title makes it hard to get a good score with Levenshtein algorithm against a longer or shorter indexed title.

Comment: How about this? https://regex101.com/r/nQfHv4/1 `([\w-]+)\[(?:[^]]*(?:[BEI]-NP-singular|B-PP)[^]]*)]`

Comment: Why `Whole New Mind` and not `A Whole New Mind`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to tackle the whole problem in one step I'd probably break it down into 2 parts:

- Parse the output from the LanguageTool CLI into structured objects
- Query the objects to find the sequences of words you're interested in

This has a couple of advantages:

- Easier to maintain as the query can be changed without having to worry about all the parsing logic that's also embedded in the same regex - you won't break the parsing when you try to change the query
- Easier to test the parse vs query steps in isolation

Admittedly, it's quite a lot more code but hopefully it reads more clearly than an arcane regex that you can't decypher when you come back to it in 6 months time...

#### Parsing

Given a string like:

```
<S> A[a/DT,B-NP-singular] Whole[whole/JJ,whole/NN,whole/RP,I-NP-singular] New[New/JJ,New/NNP,new/JJ,I-NP-singular] Mind[mind/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] Why[why/CC,why/NN,why/UH,why/WRB,B-ADVP] Right-Brainers[Right-Brainers/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] Will[will/MD,B-VP] Rule[rule/VB,I-VP] the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] Future[future/JJ,future/NN:UN,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>
```

The following code breaks it down into a list of parts (I'm not sure what the correct LanguageTool terminology is)...

```
function ConvertFrom-LanguageToolTags
{
    param( [string] $Value )
    
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
    Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest";

    # notes
    # -----
    # * see https://community.languagetool.org/analysis/analyzeText
    # * pos => part-of-speech

    # split the input string into parts
    # e.g.
    #
    #   "<S> the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] Future[future/JJ,future/NN:UN,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>"
    # 
    # becomes
    #
    #   pos  => "<S>"
    #   word => "the[the/DT,B-NP-singular]"
    #   word => "Future[future/JJ,future/NN:UN,</S>,E-NP-singular]"
    #   pos  => "<P/>"
    #
    $pos_pattern  = "(?<pos><(?<pos_name>.+?)/?>)";
    $word_pattern = "(?<word>(?<word_value>\S+?)\[(?<word_attribs>.*?)\])";
    $parts        = [regex]::Matches($value, "$pos_pattern|$word_pattern");

    $parts | foreach-object {

        # e.g. "<S>"
        # e.g. "<P/>"
        $capture = $_.Groups["pos"];
        if( $capture.Success )
        {
            return [pscustomobject] @{
                "Type"    = $capture.Name
                "Pos"     = $_.Groups["pos_name"].Value
                "Token"   = $null
                "Attribs" = @()
                "Chunks"  = @()
                "Text"    = $capture.Value
            };
        }

        # e.g. "Future[future/JJ,future/NN:UN,</S>,E-NP-singular]"
        # e.g. "Bit[bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular]"
        $capture = $_.Groups["word"];
        if( $capture.Success )
        {
            $word_attribs = $_.Groups["word_attribs"].Value.Split(",")
            return [pscustomobject] @{
                "Type"    = $capture.Name
                "Pos"     = $null
                "Token"   = $_.Groups["word_value"].Value
                "Attribs" = $word_attribs[0..($word_attribs.Length-2)]
                "Chunks"  = $word_attribs[-1].Split("|")
                "Text"    = $capture.Value
            };
        }

    }

}
```

Usage:

```
$text = "<S> A[a/DT,B-NP-singular] Whole[whole/JJ,whole/NN,whole/RP,I-NP-singular] New[New/JJ,New/NNP,new/JJ,I-NP-singular] Mind[mind/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] Why[why/CC,why/NN,why/UH,why/WRB,B-ADVP] Right-Brainers[Right-Brainers/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] Will[will/MD,B-VP] Rule[rule/VB,I-VP] the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] Future[future/JJ,future/NN:UN,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>""
$parts = ConvertFrom-LanguageToolTags $text
$parts | format-table
```

Results:

```
Type Pos Token          Attribs                           Chunks                         Text
---- --- -----          -------                           ------                         ----
pos  S                  {}                                {}                             <S>
word     A              {a/DT}                            {B-NP-singular}                A[a/DT,B-NP-singular]
word     Whole          {whole/JJ, whole/NN, whole/RP}    {I-NP-singular}                Whole[whole/JJ,whole/NN,whole/RP,I-NP-singular]
word     New            {New/JJ, New/NNP, new/JJ}         {I-NP-singular}                New[New/JJ,New/NNP,new/JJ,I-NP-singular]
word     Mind           {mind/NN:UN}                      {E-NP-singular}                Mind[mind/NN:UN,E-NP-singular]
word     Why            {why/CC, why/NN, why/UH, why/WRB} {B-ADVP}                       Why[why/CC,why/NN,why/UH,why/WRB,B-ADVP]
word     Right-Brainers {Right-Brainers/null}             {B-NP-singular, E-NP-singular} Right-Brainers[Right-Brainers/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular]
word     Will           {will/MD}                         {B-VP}                         Will[will/MD,B-VP]
word     Rule           {rule/VB}                         {I-VP}                         Rule[rule/VB,I-VP]
word     the            {the/DT}                          {B-NP-singular}                the[the/DT,B-NP-singular]
word     Future         {future/JJ, future/NN:UN, </S>}   {E-NP-singular}                Future[future/JJ,future/NN:UN,</S>,E-NP-singular]
pos  P                  {}                                {}                             <P/>
```

### Querying

Once we've got the list of tokens we can inspect it using object properties rather than text manipulation.

To implement your rules you could do something like this:

```
function Get-SearchTerms
{
    param( $parts )

    $i = 0;
    while( $i -lt $parts.Length )
    {

        # matches sequence
        #
        #   {B-NP-singular, E-NP-singular}
        #   {B-PP}
        #   {B-NP-singular, E-NP-singular}
        #
        if( (($i + 2) -lt $parts.Length) -and
            ($parts[$i].Type -eq "word") -and
             $parts[$i].Chunks.Contains("B-NP-singular") -and
             $parts[$i].Chunks.Contains("E-NP-singular") -and
            ($parts[$i+1].Type -eq "word") -and
             $parts[$i+1].Chunks.Contains("B-PP") -and
            ($parts[$i+2].Type -eq "word") -and
             $parts[$i+2].Chunks.Contains("B-NP-singular") -and
             $parts[$i+2].Chunks.Contains("E-NP-singular")
        )
        {
            $parts[$i..($i+2)].Token -join " "
            $i += 3;
        }

        # matches sequences
        #
        #   {B-NP-singular, E-NP-singular}
        #
        # or
        #
        #   {B-NP-singular}
        #   ...
        #   {E-NP-singular}
        #
        elseif( $parts[$i].Chunks.Contains("B-NP-singular") )
        {
            $start = $i;
            while( -not $parts[$i].Chunks.Contains("E-NP-singular") )
            {
                $i++;
            }
            $parts[$start..$i].Token -join " "
            $i++;
        }

        # not part of a sequence we're interested in - skip it
        else
        {
            $i += 1;
        }

    }

}
```

Usage:

```
$text = "<S> A[a/DT,B-NP-singular] Whole[whole/JJ,whole/NN,whole/RP,I-NP-singular] New[New/JJ,New/NNP,new/JJ,I-NP-singular] Mind[mind/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] Why[why/CC,why/NN,why/UH,why/WRB,B-ADVP] Right-Brainers[Right-Brainers/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] Will[will/MD,B-VP] Rule[rule/VB,I-VP] the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] Future[future/JJ,future/NN:UN,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>""
$parts = ConvertFrom-LanguageToolTags $text

Get-SearchTerms $parts
```

Results:

```
A Whole New Mind
Right-Brainers
the Future
```

As a personal style I'd rather go with this longer low-tech approach than an extended regex, but ymmv...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start.  Not sure what you need.  I extracted the values to a table.  Looks like you can use split to get the items you need from the table

Here is the Regex

```
$inputs = @(
   '<S> A[a/DT,B-NP-singular] Whole[whole/JJ,whole/NN,whole/RP,I-NP-singular] New[New/JJ,New/NNP,new/JJ,I-NP-singular] Mind[mind/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] Why[why/CC,why/NN,why/UH,why/WRB,B-ADVP] Right-Brainers[Right-Brainers/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] Will[will/MD,B-VP] Rule[rule/VB,I-VP] the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] Future[future/JJ,future/NN:UN,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>',
   ' <S> Bit[bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] By[by/IN,by/JJ,by/NN,by/RP,B-PP] Bit[bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] How[how/WRB,B-ADVP] P2P[P2P/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] Is[Is/NNP,be/VBZ,B-VP] Changing[change/VBG,I-VP] the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] World[world/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] by[by/IN,B-PP] John[John/NNP,B-NP-singular] Smith[Smith/NNP,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>'
)

$pattern = '\s?(?<key>[^\[]+)\[(?<value>[^\]]+)\]\s+'
foreach($input in $inputs)
{
   $table = @{}
   $matches = $input | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $pattern 
   foreach($match in $matches.Matches) 
   { 
      $table[$match.groups['key'].value] = $match.groups['value'].value 
   }
}
```

Here is the table from second input

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
By                             by/IN,B-PP
the                            the/DT,B-NP-singular
Bit                            bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular
Changing                       change/VBG,I-VP
<S> Bit                        bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular
World                          world/NN:UN,E-NP-singular
John                           John/NNP,B-NP-singular
P2P                            P2P/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular
Is                             Is/NNP,be/VBZ,B-VP
How                            how/WRB,B-ADVP
```

Comment: The goal is to capture the noun pairs, e.g. "Whole New Mind" or "Bit by Bit" in the example

Comment: As an aside: `$input` is an [automatic (built-in) variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) that should not be used for custom purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I got a not very beautiful, but, in my opinion, a working regular expression.

```
(?i)([\w-]+)\[[^\[]*(?:(?:(?:(?:B-NP-singular\|)?E-NP-singular|I-NP-singular)[^\]]*\])|(?:B-NP-singular|B-PP)[^\]]*\](?=[^\[]+\[[^\]]*E-NP-singular[^\]]*\]))
```

This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?i)                   set flags for this block (case- insensitive)
                       (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                       matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                       normally)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
(                      group and capture to \1:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\w-]+                 any character of: word characters (a-z, A-Z,
                         0-9, _), '-' (1 or more times (matching the
                         most amount possible))
---------------------------------------------------------------------
)                      end of \1
---------------------------------------------------------------------
\[                     '['
---------------------------------------------------------------------
[^\[]*                 any character except: '\[' (0 or more times
                       (matching the most amount possible))
---------------------------------------------------------------------
(?:                    group, but do not capture:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                    group, but do not capture:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                    group, but do not capture:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                    group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------
        B-NP-                  'B-NP-singular'
        singular
---------------------------------------------------------------------
        \|                     '|'
---------------------------------------------------------------------
      )?                     end of grouping
---------------------------------------------------------------------
      E-NP-singular          'E-NP-singular'
---------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                      OR
---------------------------------------------------------------------
      I-NP-singular          'I-NP-singular'
---------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                      end of grouping
---------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\]]*                 any character except: '\]' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
------------------------------------------------------------------
    \]                     ']'
------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                      end of grouping
------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                      OR
------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                    group, but do not capture:
------------------------------------------------------------------
    B-NP-singular          'B-NP-singular'
------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                      OR
------------------------------------------------------------------
    B-PP                   'B-PP'
------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                      end of grouping
------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\]]*                 any character except: '\]' (0 or more
                         times (matching the most amount
                         possible))
------------------------------------------------------------------
  \]                     ']'
------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                    look ahead to see if there is:
------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\[]+                 any character except: '\[' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                     '['
------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\]]*                 any character except: '\]' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
------------------------------------------------------------------
    E-NP-singular          'E-NP-singular'
------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\]]*                 any character except: '\]' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
------------------------------------------------------------------
    \]                     ']'
------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                      end of look-ahead
------------------------------------------------------------------
)                      end of grouping
```

```
$inputs =
  '<S> A[a/DT,B-NP-singular] Whole[whole/JJ,whole/NN,whole/RP,I-NP-singular] New[New/JJ,New/NNP,new/JJ,I-NP-singular] Mind[mind/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] Why[why/CC,why/NN,why/UH,why/WRB,B-ADVP] Right-Brainers[Right-Brainers/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] Will[will/MD,B-VP] Rule[rule/VB,I-VP] the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] Future[future/JJ,future/NN:UN,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>',
  '<S> Bit[bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] By[by/IN,by/JJ,by/NN,by/RP,B-PP] Bit[bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] How[how/WRB,B-ADVP] P2P[P2P/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] Is[Is/NNP,be/VBZ,B-VP] Changing[change/VBG,I-VP] the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] World[world/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] by[by/IN,B-PP] John[John/NNP,B-NP-singular] Smith[Smith/NNP,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>'

$re = [regex]'(?i)([\w-]+)\[[^\[]*(?:(?:(?:(?:B-NP-singular\|)?E-NP-singular|I-NP-singular)[^\]]*\])|(?:B-NP-singular|B-PP)[^\]]*\](?=[^\[]+\[[^\]]*E-NP-singular[^\]]*\]))'

$captured = @{}

foreach($str in $inputs) {
  $captured[$str] = @()
  $phrase = $delim = ''
  $pos = 0
  foreach($m in $re.matches($str)) {
    if( $pos -ne 0 -and $pos + 1 -lt $m.index ) {
      $captured[$str] += $phrase
      $delim = $phrase = ''
    }
    $phrase += $delim + $m.Groups[1].Value
    $delim = ' '
    $pos = $m.index + $m.length
  }
  if( $phrase -ne '' ) { $captured[$str] += $phrase }
}

$captured | Format-List
```

Output.

```
Name  : <S> A[a/DT,B-NP-singular] 
        Whole[whole/JJ,whole/NN,whole/RP,I-NP-singular] 
        New[New/JJ,New/NNP,new/JJ,I-NP-singular] 
        Mind[mind/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] 
        Why[why/CC,why/NN,why/UH,why/WRB,B-ADVP] 
        Right-Brainers[Right-Brainers/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] 
        Will[will/MD,B-VP] Rule[rule/VB,I-VP] the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] 
        Future[future/JJ,future/NN:UN,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>
Value : {Whole New Mind, Right-Brainers, the Future}

Name  : <S> Bit[bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] 
        By[by/IN,by/JJ,by/NN,by/RP,B-PP] 
        Bit[bit/NN,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] How[how/WRB,B-ADVP] 
        P2P[P2P/null,B-NP-singular|E-NP-singular] Is[Is/NNP,be/VBZ,B-VP] 
        Changing[change/VBG,I-VP] the[the/DT,B-NP-singular] 
        World[world/NN:UN,E-NP-singular] by[by/IN,B-PP] 
        John[John/NNP,B-NP-singular] Smith[Smith/NNP,</S>,E-NP-singular]<P/>
Value : {Bit By Bit, P2P, the World, John Smith}
```

Try in on [tio.run](https://tio.run/##jVRtb5swEP7Or/CHSECB0O5jlZeVZG0TrQglayLNYRJJnGDJgciAaNTkt2dnE@hgXVcpPp/tu3ue52yyj3PCk5Awdj63aLTP0gR1FYTUzrSH7nBgD3@YjuV6VkKjbcYC7qN5GDOCc2Ht8dgsHNe9OBPPHNXjXZJjGCJWTK7rmVGxbAQ@0WiNd2Ag5vbZNb81cQ@AerAHA1NMEvFgPz/KaT5xgOfdcOb5aEK3YWo5PKARaMP1pR1ljNUlHZtAlDGcg7GfhhApS2YgmYOxZw7QFltpSDCMdxp0n6UZJ3gjJ6Hz4hWqOva015DW8eyeapZdd2iKlzQVAj@k6Rzw8mCPXBMsgCxlS8DCDTiWBww/W@gxznEY57Ueel88DOMT3RoleJTIW12K7vy8dGwQBtEWgvBKOOLk4b@Nm8ecrXEu7PtPYFlKLgSO4zDCwkj4RrHpjqYhllYe/6vvitLiBHUR5mRLXnxV61Ndw4vc8g19gfGvBfavtP5t9avBLI56v1bzWHvTOqT7/tXC14/NzKOQUJ1r/a5EMiQibNWKVlV0wXYV7MVzWgPnr68nRdnEnASrUGslKUc0QpfPWEev8KKqaCyOfZGj6WJ/H/IgEbpba8LoDhxVlfsx/AGga3CrujtZlZP2LkhXIUkkkl7UR4hutCLLigi6RlYQrYu1gW6QxVLU2rXhmyYvqMz4m5XRLQmVASWpN56SHkInactto@JvCJwHHmf7BN/47VnAsqLYmz6kXnKlxIqWzGQk2qahUtQvJBUIQpWqCu4fsIas0583c0T3MYduWd9pkirn828) and/or [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cNwvxb/2).